# Power BI DAX how to create new column showing Last Friday of the month based on another date column

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

Is there a way to calculate the Last Friday of the month based on another date column.

I created a date column using

```
Date = CALENDAR(DATE(2015, 01, 01), DATE(2022, 12,31))
```

I know that I can use EOMONTH() in a new column to return the end of month for each date but is how would we return the Last Friday of that month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
Column = 
VAR eom = EOMONTH('Date'[Date],0)
VAR day = WEEKDAY('Date'[Date],1)

RETURN  IF(day == 6  &&  DAY('Date'[Date]) >= DAY(eom-7), TRUE() )
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

```
Measure = 
VAR d =  DATESBETWEEN ('Date'[Date],  EOMONTH(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Column1]),0)-6, EOMONTH(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Column1]),0))
VAR f = FILTER(d, WEEKDAY( 'Date'[Date]) = 6)

RETURN 

MAXX(f, [Date])
```

Comment: This returns TRUE/FALSE statements. I was looking for the Date of the last friday of that month.

So for example if the date is 17/06/2021, I would like a new column that would return 25/06/2021 as this is the date of the last Friday in that month

Comment: I'll update now but please be more explicit when asking questions in future. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for help, I will keep this in mind in future

Comment: yes - just seen this morning. Thanks for all your help!